# Hacer algo después de subir archivos en Dropzone

Tags: vue.js, dropzone

Estoy subiendo unos archivos desde Dropzone. Cuando le doy en un botón, entonces se suben en cola pero después de que se hayan subido los archivos me gustaría hacer algo más.

Como redireccionar la página.

```
dropOptions() {
    return {
        url: '/publicacion/' + pub,
        paramName: 'archivo',
        chunkSize: 500, // Bytes
        addRemoveLinks: true,
        autoProcessQueue: false,
        dictDefaultMessage: 'Arrastrar archivos',
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        }
    };
},
```

Cuando presiono mi botón, antes de subir los archivos, hago otras cosas,si todo sale correcto. Entonces  hago esto, se suben los archivos al servidor.

```
this.$refs.myUniqueID.processQueue()
```

E inclusive le apliqué una clase a mi botón " De cargando " pero pues se queda ahí aunque los archivos ya hayan subido.
Por eso me gustaría hacer algo, después de que se hayan cargado todos los archivos.

Estoy usando vue + laravel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dropzone funciona, *grosso modo*, con Events. Entonces, cuando pasa un evento se lanza una función que, si tienes definida, puedes modificar el comportamiento por defecto (que es no hacer nada). E.g.:

```
myDropzone.on("complete", function() {
   // hacer algo
});
```

La lista de eventos la tienes [aquí](https://www.dropzonejs.com/#event-list).

Comment: Claro que no fue tan Mero en el clavo, pero suficiente para entender los eventos. Ahora todo funciona.